# Changing the default home page (non programatically) wiki SP 2007

Tags: wiki

I am brand new to SP. I have been charged with creating a site for our group. I posted a question last Friday regarding my default home page, where the view generated always has a grey bar on the bottom with a 'custom column' showing. In other words, I have my home page, and an ugly grey bar on the bottom that says "Knowledge Area'. Every page that is created within this library has this bar. That is fine by me for the other pages, but so ugly on the home.

So then I got the idea to create a new library, and reproduce the home page there, and just modify the welcome page settings to that page.

Unfortunately, when I follow siteactions > site settings, under Look and Feel there is no link to 'Welcome Page' (as I had read on the internets).

How the heck can I modify the home page path? I have no access to SP designer, or any other way to reach any code (near as I can tell).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need the publishing features enabled to see the link to welcome page from site settings.  Are you using SharePoint Foundation or Server?

Comment: I apologize for sounding like a complete tool, but when I say I am brand new to SP, I mean brand new... I am on a work placement through my tech school, and the company I am woring for has me working on 'Sharepoint work'. How can you tell which you are using?

Comment: When you go to site settings, then site collection administration, and then site collection features, do you have an option to enable SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure??

Comment: Not that I can see, no... In site settings, I have: Users and PERMISSIONS > People and Groups, Advanced Permissions.    LOOK AND FEEL > Title, description, and icon, Navigation, Tree view, Reset to site definition, Searchable columns.  GALLERIES > Master pages, site content types, Site columns.   SITE ADMINISTRATION > Regional settings, Site libraries and lists, Site usage reports, User alerts, RSS, Search visibility, Site features, Delete this site, Content and structure.

Comment: It sounds like we don't know if you have that feature or not because you aren't a site collection admin.  I think you will need to request that before we can take the next step.

Comment: Appreciate that. I have given thought to the structure of this site, and may re-organize the entire thing. I have a question that I am going to post regarding that....